# Variable disappears after memmem function

Tags: c, pointers, substring

I have 2 projects: I wrote a first C program that substrings words and it worked well. Then I needed the same code for a second project: I copied and pasted the code block below from the first project to second project. Unfortunately, It doesn't work on the second project. The `r` variable disappeared. I debugged both projects at the same time with the same content. But after the `memmem` operation, the `r` value disappeared. `ptr` is a `u_int8_t` and parameter.

```
const u_int8_t *r,
r = ptr
r = ( const u_int8_t *)memmem(r + 1, len - (r - ptr) - 2, tag, tl);
```

Thank you.

"the value disappeared" means that IDE doesn't show the variable after `memmem` operation on the debug mode.

Here is the source code:

```
char *gettag(const void *ptr, unsigned long len, const char *tag, unsigned long *gettaglen) {
    unsigned long register r, l, tl;
    char *rc;

    tl = strlen(tag);
    r = (unsigned long)memmem(ptr, len, tag, tl);
    if (r == 0) {
        l = 0;
    } else {
        r += tl;
        l = (unsigned long)memmem((void *)r, len - (r - (unsigned long)ptr), "\r\n", 2);
        if (l > 0) {
            l -= r;
        } else {
            l = 0;
            r = 0;
        }
    }
    rc = (char*)r;
    if (rc) {
        while (rc[0] == ' ') {
            rc++;
            l--;
        }
    }
    *gettaglen = l;
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: The question is very unclear. What does "value disappeared" mean? Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code, the input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: "the value  disappeared" means that IDE doesn't show the variable after memmem operation on the debug mode. @kaylum

Comment: What IDE? Don't you think it would make sense to tell us at least that much? And doesn't show where? We can't see what you are looking at so you need to describe the problem much more clearly. Normally screen shots are discouraged for SO questions but in this case that may help.

Comment: I am using QT Creator on Ubuntu 16.04. @kaylum

Comment: @Ms.Sahin Are you debugging an optimized build, by any chance? Depending on how you use `r` later on, the compiler is allowed to not even assign it a memory/stack location but instead store it in a register for just as long as it needs it.

Comment: You should post the full source code for both projects so we can understand your problem. Posting a code fragment does not help.

Comment: You should not cast the result of `memmem`

Comment: I added source code. @chqrlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I added below code block and It worked.

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
void *memmem(const void* haystack, size_t hl, const void* needle, size_t nl);
#endif
```

Haters gonna hate.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should include `<string.h>` where `memmem` is declared on GNU systems if the identifier `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined.
- you should define `r` and `l` as a `char *` and `len`, `tl` and `l` as a `size_t`.
- `register` is useless nowadays.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <string.h>

char *gettag(const void *ptr, size_t len, const char *tag, unsigned long *gettaglen) {
    size_t tl = strlen(tag);
    size_t taglen = 0;
    char *r, *l, *rc = NULL;

    r = memmem(ptr, len, tag, tl);
    if (r != NULL) {
        r += tl;
        l = memmem(r, len - (r - ptr), "\r\n", 2);
        if (l != NULL) {
            rc = r;
            while (*rc == ' ') {
                rc++;
            }
            taglen = l - rc;
        }
    }
    *gettaglen = taglen;
    return rc;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

that's because of compiler optimization
you need write "volatile" before variable name
remember compilers automatically remove unused variables

```
volatile const uint8_t *r,
r = ptr
r = (const uint8_t*) memmem(r+1, len-(r-ptr)-2, tag, tl);
```

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is not addressing the OP's problem: `volatile` is way beyond her skill level. The problem is a much more basic one, but the full source code is missing.